# How to get object properties like IE object monitoring

Tags: javascript, activexobject

If I create an instance of an `ActiveXObject`, I would be able to get the display name like IE does in its object monitoring section. In this case (a XmlHttpRequest as example) I'd like to be able to get the string `"[object IXMLHTTPRequest]"` - as highlighted in gray below.

[image]

I tried several things I've read online, but none of them work for me:

- `ToString()` the object → not supported
- get the `constructor` → gets `undefined`
- `JSON.stringify` that piece → empty json

[image]

So in conclusion, how can I get the display name of an object created through `ActiveX`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't. `xhr` is a COM object, it doesn't have all the methods and properties a regular JS object would have.

Comment: Yes i have noticed this.. but is there any way to do so? I really have to get the name.

Comment: There's no way to get the Class, even `Object.prototype.toString.call(xhr)` will return you `[Object object]`.